# jQuery div swap code issue

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that works great for a simple div swap with fade.

```
$(".panelswap1").click(function () {
        $(".panelswap1").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".panelswap2").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });

    $(".panelswap2").click(function () {
        $(".panelswap2").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".panelswap1").fadeToggle("slow")
        });
    });
```

My issue is if I want to add more than one div in my project that has the swap I have to add more lines of code.

```
$(".panelswap1").click(function () {
        $(".panelswap1").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".panelswap2").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });

    $(".panelswap2").click(function () {
        $(".panelswap2").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".panelswap1").fadeToggle("slow")
        });
    });

    $(".panelswap3").click(function () {
        $(".panelswap3").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".panelswap4").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });

    $(".panelswap4").click(function () {
        $(".panelswap4").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(".panelswap3").fadeToggle("slow")
        });
    });
```

If I want ten swap div/panels, that's alot of jQuery, is there a way to simplify it to be more general so I can just use the two classes .panelswap1 and 2 on multiple instances.

HTML

```
<div class="panelswap1">
                    Content
                </div>

                <div class="panelswap2">
                    Content swap
                </div>

<div class="panelswap3">
                    Content
                </div>

                <div class="panelswap4">
                    Content swap
                </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the html tree relationship between these panels? A simple example of your html structure would likely turn this into just a couple of lines that would scale to any quantity

Comment: HTML added, though I don't think it will help

Comment: actually it's important ... each pair could easily be in different parts of page. Always post html with your script if it's relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your structure is something like:

```
<div>
   <div class="panelswap1"></div>
   <div class="panelswap2"></div>
</div>
<div>
   <div class="panelswap3"></div>
   <div class="panelswap4"></div>
</div>
```

the first thing you would want to do is get rid of all the incremetal classes and make them common ones

```
<div class="panel-group">
   <div class="panelswap"></div>
   <div class="panelswap hidden"></div> <!-- hidden class for page load -->
</div>
```

Then you can target one class and one click handler for all

```
$('.panelswap').click(function(){
    // "this" inside event handler is element in selector collection that event occurs on
    var $panel = $(this).stop(true,true).fadeToggle('slow', function(){
         $panel.siblings('.panelswap').stop(true,true).fadeToggle('slow');
    }); 
});
```

The use of `stop()` is to kill any existing animation if user clicks while animation in progress.

If outer wrapper is a problem..can be adjusted but having the wrapper is the most common approach for this sort of repeating group

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/00Lp6qjb/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

May be You can create a function like this

```
function swap(p1,p2){
    $(p1).click(function () {
        $(p1).fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(p2).fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: This is along the right track . . . a more complete answer would indicate how to attach the function to the click, as well as how to pass the parameters . . .